# Buying air tickets for 5 people

Tags: tickets, airlines, group-travel

I am planning a group trip to Busan, Korea and I realized that each round trip ticket is about 1.2k. the issue is trying to have everyone sit next to each other, but this requires someone paying for all the tickets. All of us do not have a credit card that can cover 5-6k and no one wants to charge that large of an amount their debit card. Has anyone encounter this problem before, or have any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Go speak to a travel agent--they'll be able to charge each ticket separately.

Comment: alternatively you can all buy your tickets online at the same time presuming you can select your own seats.  Of course there is a risk.  Also if the plane is not full you can request the airline to move your seat. 5 people will likely have to be split up somehow as not many planes have a row of 5 seats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities here and which one will work really depends on your situation. Here is a list of a few things you could do:

- Book through an agency offering split payments. There are a couple of them around. This way everyone can pay their part. For example ba.com offers this service.
- Go to or phone up a travel organisation and have them bill each of you separately. (As commented by @waiwai933)
- Old fashionedly put money together and have one person pay.
- Buy tickets separately and risk not sitting together or maybe not even on the same flight. Start a booking for your maximum amount of tickets in this case so you are sure the amount of tickets is available. Then you should be able to get on the same flight with some certainty. There is always a risk of course.
- Check in online and as early as possible. This will allow you to choose seats next to each other if possible.
- Pay extra and reserve seats.

Most of all though: Phone up the airline/agency and see what they can do for you. This will probably not be the first time they hear this and they may be able to help you or give you some better advice than a random person on the internet can give. Let us know what you did in the end?